# Android Studio - update library that is used in multiple projects (update ALL references)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a library that I use in many projects. Now I want to adjust this library (rename packages, split the library in smaller parts, move classes ...).

If I open one of my apps projects and adjust the library, the app project is adjusted too (all references and similar). But all other projects won't be updated.

**Questions**

How can I do above thing so that android studio updates all my app projects at once? Is that somehow possible? (it's ok if I have to tell android studio which projects it should check as well, that would make things a lot easier already...)

Can I somehow put all projects in some sort of a master project and adjust the library afterwards?

Comment: You get something wrong. I want to use features like "drag&drop" classes and like "code refactoring"... I want to use this feature and automatically update all PROJECTS at once. The code in all my apps should be updated (as if I would open one project and use the features in my modules)